# Probability $k$ experiments without heads

Tags: probability

Experiment of throwing $2$ fair coins. After $n$ tosses ,let $S_n=k$ be the number of tosses with no heads. What is the probability $\mathbb{P}(S_n=k)$:

Sample space $\Omega=\{(w,w),(w,k),(k,w),(k,k)\}$. Success= no heads

$$p=\mathbb{P}(\text{no head})=\mathbb{P}(w,w)=\frac{1}{4}$$

Failure $q=1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$.

$$\mathbb{P}(S_n=k)=\mathbb{P}(k ~\text{successes})={n \choose k}(1/4)^k(3/4)^{n-k}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$S_n$ follows Binomial distribution, $Bin(n, \frac14)$.